# How to dynamically match nodes by configuration in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to match two xml files based on a dynamic configuration xml.

Xml A

```
<item>
  <title>Title</title>
  <value>5</value>
  <pc>test</pc>
</item>
<item>
  <title>Title</title>
  <value>9</value>
  <pc>test 2</pc>
</item>
```

Xml B

```
<item>
  <title>Title</title>
  <value>5</value>
  <pc>123</pc>
</item>
```

Configuration

```
<item>
  <title />
  <value />
</item>
```

The configuration xml states that I need to match item nodes by the children `<title>` and `<value>`.

Matching Xml A to XML B, the matching node is:

```
<item>
  <title>Title</title>
  <value>5</value>
  <pc>test</pc>
</item>
```

And the non matching node is

```
<item>
  <title>Title</title>
  <value>9</value>
  <pc>test 2</pc>
</item>
```

Is this possible in XSLT 1.0 without dynamic select statements?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to restrict yourself to XSLT 1.0 for a problem like this.

But consider using XSLT to generate an XSLT stylesheet that does the matching.

I don't fully understand the semantics of your little query language, but taking B as your primary input and Config as secondary, you could fairly easily generate the expression/pattern `item[title='Title'][value='5']` which you could generate into a stylesheet which you then run against A.